# Format Exception:String was not found as valid datetime

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i am using mvvm..for validating dateofbirth field,it is combo-box control,i have set Dob property as string.bt it shows error..using this dateofbirth am calculating age..Is der anyway to make the Dob datepicker as required field,if it is string we can check it as empty or not in idataerror info,bt if it is datetime we cannot,then is der another way to make it as required field???..help me

property is set like below

```
public string Dob
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.Dob;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.Dob = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Dob");
                OnPropertyChanged("Age");
            }
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                    return employee.Age = DateTime.Today.Year - (Convert.ToDateTime(Dob)).Year;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.Age = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Age");
            }

        }
```

Shows error at (Convert.ToDateTime(Dob)) like

String was not recognized as valid datetime!Format exception when am starting running the app,it immediately shows the error..please give me a solution

Comment: what sense does a setter have if you calculate the value always from Dob? My guess is that you are calling on Startup somehwere Age and because Dob is empty the error occurs

Comment: i cudnt understand that..

Comment: Why don't you use a nullable DateTime: `DateTime?` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for you to use Dob as String Type? If not you can use this

```
public DateTime Dob
{
    get
    {
        return employee.Dob;
    }
    set
    {
        employee.Dob = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Dob");
        OnPropertyChanged("Age");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be the DateTime-formats. Try using explicit formats while converting and assigning these DateTime-properties.

But, why don't you do the calculation of the age in your employee-class? Like so:

```
public int Age
{
    get { return DateTime.Today.Year - Dob.Year; }
    set 
    { 
        int years = value - Age;
        Dob.AddYears(years);
    }
}
```

And as type you use a nullable `DateTime?`, so you can still check if it's empty and if not, cast it:

```
if (Dob != null)
{
    DateTime dob = (DateTime)Dob;
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: where i hav to cast..i dont understand

Comment: Everywhere you want to use it as DateTime. You have to cast a nullable to its original type (e.g. `DateTime?` to `DateTime`) to access it's properties. That's why you should check first if it's not null to not get any exceptions.